# video stream between multiple maschines

Tags: ros, multiplemachines

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi There,

I'm working on a UAV which is equipped with a webcam. The webcam is running with the usb_cam package and it is working fine on the UAV Machine.
Now I'm trying to send the image-data via wireless to the base station but I can't get the messages. I exported the Master to the UAV and can even see which topics are published there, but when I try rostopic hz /logitech_usb_webcam/image_raw I don't recieve any message.

Could that be a result of two different versions of ROS (UAV = diamondback / Base = electric) or is that a failure somewhere else? would be great to get some help.

Cheers

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33435/video-stream-between-multiple-maschines/) by [dinamex](https://answers.ros.org/users/1383/dinamex/) on ROS Answers with karma: 447 on 2012-05-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As Dan already said, you should check the ROS [NetworkSetup](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/NetworkSetup).

In this case i assume that the error is caused by your /etc/hosts file. You should be aware that local entries in the /etc/hosts file overwrite entries of your DHCP server...

---

Originally posted by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) with karma: 2108 on 2012-05-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dinamex](https://answers.ros.org/users/1383/dinamex/) on 2012-05-07**:
Thanks for the quick response. I worked only with the IP's to set an alias in the /etc/hosts file was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This sounds like a network/ROS environment configuration issue. My first thought would be to make sure that on your UAV, ROS_IP is set to the externally accessible IP address of the UAV. Take a look at the [NetworkSetup](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/NetworkSetup) wiki page for more troubleshooting suggestions.

It's generally not a good idea to mix versions of ROS, though I doubt that is the cause of this particular problem.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2012-05-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4